# Error TS2305: Module '"../../../node_modules/@types/uuid"' has no exported member 'validate'

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, uuid

I am using node.js version 14.15.4 and typescript version: 4.6.3
And I upgraded uuid package version to 8.3.2: https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

It's written in the docs of the package that there is uuid.validate() method in the new version.
I am getting this error: '"../../../node_modules/@types/uuid"' has no exported member 'validate'
I tried remove node_modules and package-lock and npm install again but the error still exist.

I see inside the node_modules folder the uuid folder and the package.json says it "8.3.2".

What can I do to resolve it?